# How are two different appservices identified

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

How are two appservices in the same appservice plan uniquely identified though I understand they have different urls but it is explained that at the backend this urls are converted into IP addresses however the appservices have the same Outbound IP addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs are not converted into IP addresses on the backend side, domain names like myapp.azurewebsites.net are resolved to IP addresses by DNS servers - and afterwards the client sends an HTTP request to the derived IP address which belongs to a server on Azure side. Indeed this means that the Azure backend wouldn't be able to assign a request to the right app service so there is another property necessary for this matching - which is the [HTTP Host header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host). This header is used by an internal load balancer (called a "front end" on Azure side) which distributes the request to the worker(s) your application is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the inbound and outbound IP addresses has little to do with the selection of app services running on ASP's, the outbound IP can even be totally different than the ASP addresses if you are using a NAT GateWay or other services.

If you want a more specific answer please ask a more specific question as in what problem are you trying to resolve?